# The lower bound of operator norm

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces, matrix-analysis

The operator norm of a mapping $\mathcal{A}:\mathbb{R}^{n_1\times n_2} \to \mathbb{R}^{n_1\times n_2}$ is defined by
$$
\|\mathcal{A}\|=\sup_{\|X\|_{F} \leq 1}\|\mathcal{A}(X)\|_{F},
$$
where $X$ is a matrice, and $\|\cdot\|_{F}$ is $F$-norm defined by $\|X\|=\left<X,X\right>^{\frac{1}{2}}$.

If we have $\|\mathcal{A}\| \leq \kappa$, where $\kappa > 0$ is a constant, then we can get $\|\mathcal{A}(X)\|_{F}\leq \kappa \|X\|_{F}$ by the definition of operator norm. Can we find a constant $c >0$ such that $\|\mathcal{A}(X)\|_{F}\geq c \|X\|_{F}$. If not, can we add additional conditions to find thid $c$?

Comment: In general, such a $c$ will not exist. If $\mathcal A$ has a non-zero element $X_0$ in the kernel, then $\lVert \mathcal A(X_0) \rVert=0$ which will never be $\ge c \lVert X \rVert_F$. 
If $\mathcal A$ is a linear operator, having a non-zero kernel element is equivalent to not being injective. In the case of $\mathcal A$ being injective such a constant exists - it is the operator norm of the inverse $\mathcal A^{-1}$.